# Generating random edges with probability between nodes multiple times in R?

Tags: r, random, igraph, network-analysis

So I want to generate a random network with 3 nodes. And the edges have to random between the two nodes with a specific probability or strength.

Choosing the nodes with following probability : 
Node 1 :0.6
Node 2: 0.3
Node 3: 0.1

And I want to do it for multiple times as this is a part of temporal data. So in each time stamp one connection.

I am doing it in R with igraph. But the ER model could not do it.

Any idea how can I do it?

Edit: The edges are directed.
( Note : I am a biology student not a hardcore person who works with network. So any direction and suggestions will be helpful.)

Comment: Is the problem with setting the strength of the nodes each time or generating the strength such that it sums to 1 each time? For the strengths you could do the following  `x <- runif(3)` then `x <- x/sum(x)` every time you want to generate a new set of strengths

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems to be impossible. There are three possible edges: 1-2, 1-3, and 2-3. Let `p_ij` denote the probability that edge i-j is chosen. Note that the probability that a given node appears on a randomly chosen edge is the sum of the two edge probabilities that involve that node, so that e.g.

```
p(1) = p_12 + p_13
```

You seem to want the `p_ij` to satisfy:

```
p_12 + p_13 = 0.6
p_12 + p_23 = 0.3
p_13 + p_23 = 0.1
p_12 + p_13 + p_23 = 1
```

with the further constraint that each `p_ij >= 0`.

This is simply impossible. The first three equations yield `p_12 = 0.4`, `p_13 = 0.2` and `p_23 = -0.1`, which violates the fourth equation and the nonnegativity constraints.

If this argument *doesn't* imply that what you want is impossible, please explain what you are trying to do more clearly.

**On Edit:** If you want to simulate movement between nodes (as per your comments) you can do something like this:

```
#the following function takes a vector, nodes of
#populations and picks a random move of an individual
#from one node to another. Chosen source node is
#is picked with probability which is proportional
#to the population. Return value is a vector of
#the form c(from,to) 

move <- function(nodes){
  total.pop <- sum(nodes)
  n <- length(nodes)
  from <- sample(1:n,1,prob = nodes/total.pop)
  to <- sample((1:n)[-from],1)
  c(from,to)
}

#The following function takes an initial population
#distribution and simulates n moves according to the above
#it returns a dataframe with one row per step

moves <- function(nodes,steps){
  n <- length(nodes)
  current <- nodes #current nodes
  A <- matrix(0,steps+1,n+3)
  A[1,] <- c(0,c(NA,NA),nodes)
  for(i in 1:steps){
    v <- move(current)
    current[v[1]] <- current[v[1]] - 1
    current[v[2]] <- current[v[2]] + 1
    A[i+1,] <- c(i,v,current)
  }
  df <- data.frame(A)
  names(df) <- c("Step","From","To",paste("Node",1:n,sep = ""))
  df
}
```

For example:

```
> sim <- moves(c(60,30,10),1000)
> plot(sim$Step,sim$Node1,type = "l",ylim = c(0,100),xlab = "Time Step", ylab = "populations")
> points(sim$Step,sim$Node2,type = "l",col = "blue")
> points(sim$Step,sim$Node3,type = "l",col = "red")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ok. So first I want to the edges to be directed (sorry forgot to mention in question).The nodes represent number of individuals present in that node. It is known before the start of the network connections. So the strength (or what it is called) is know for the three nodes is known.The individuals can move between the nodes, thus edges between the nodes. And it is directed, individuals can move from any node to other node.

Comment: Now I have the experimental data of movement in each time frame, I want to model it by generating random edges across different time and compare it with the experimental data.

Comment: It still isn't clear what you are trying to do. Sounds closer to a Markov chain than a random network. Are you trying to simulate the movement of individuals between nodes? If an individual leaves node 1, to which node do they go and with what probabilities?

Comment: >  Are you trying to simulate the movement of individuals between nodes?  Yes. The individuals are free to move from any node to other node i.e. random. But the initial number of individuals in each node is different.